# Are Saprolings still Tokens after playing Life and Limb?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

After playing the enchantment [Life and Limb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLife%20and%20Limb%5d) all Saprolings and all Forests become "creature-land-saproling-forests" (see card rulings). My question is: Do they still have the card-type **token**? 
Meaning:

1. Is it possible to use cards which explicitly say "sacrifice a
   **nontoken** creature"?
2. Can I keep the saprolings on my hand if my opponent bounces them?
   (Tokens would be discarded.)
3. The rulings also say, newly played lands get summoning sickness. So
   they can't attack right away. Does it also apply for the mana
   ability?

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9653/are-tokens-copying-essence-of-the-wild-still-tokens

Comment: Re "*(Tokens would be discarded.)*", Tokens wouldn't be discarded; tokens would cease to exist

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, they are still tokens.**

First of all, Token is not a card type:

> 205.2a The card types are artifact, conspiracy, creature, enchantment, instant, land, phenomenon, plane, planeswalker, scheme, sorcery, tribal, and vanguard.

A token is any object on the battlefield that is not represented by a card. Note that a token is still a token even if you use an MtG card to represent it.

> 110.5. Some effects put tokens onto the battlefield. A token is a marker used to represent any permanent that isn’t represented by a card.
>
> 110.5e A token is subject to anything that affects permanents in general or that affects the token’s card type or subtype. A token isn’t a card (even if represented by a card that has a Magic back or that came from a Magic booster pack).

No effect can ever turn a token into a non-token or vice versa. All Life and Limb does is affect a permanent's card type which, as shown, has nothing to do with the object being a token or not.

That answers your questions 1 and 2. Tokens remain tokens under all circumstances and the same rules apply to them with or without Life and Limb.

Question 3 is only tangentially related to Life and Limb and is answered here:

[What is Summoning Sickness](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25234/what-is-summoning-sickness-and-how-does-it-affect-my-creatures)